# Is there a dataset for GraphQL?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I'm playing with Apollo/GraphQL on a neo4j DB

In Neo4j there is the 'Movies & Persons' Dataset

Is there something similar for GraphQL (ie Schema, Data, Queries, Mutations, ...) which I could use to play around in my demo app / connected to apollo studio sandbox explorer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to generate a schema for data on neo4j

```
import { toGraphQLTypeDefs } from "@neo4j/introspector";
import neo4j from "neo4j-driver";
import fs from 'fs';

const AURA_ENDPOINT = 'bolt://localhost:7687';
const USERNAME = 'neo4j';
const PASSWORD = 'pass';


const driver = neo4j.driver(
    AURA_ENDPOINT,
    neo4j.auth.basic(USERNAME, PASSWORD)
);

const sessionFactory = () => driver.session({ defaultAccessMode: neo4j.session.READ })

// We create a async function here until "top level await" has landed
// so we can use async/await
async function main() {
    const typeDefs = await toGraphQLTypeDefs(sessionFactory)
    fs.writeFileSync('schema.graphql', typeDefs)
    await driver.close();
}
main()
```

adapted from [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/graphql-manual/current/introspector/)

the output can be used as typedef

```
const typeDefs = gql`
  interface ActedInProperties @relationshipProperties {
    roles: [String]!
}

type Movie {
    peopleActedIn: [Person!]! @relationship(type: "ACTED_IN", direction: IN, properties: "ActedInProperties")
    peopleDirected: [Person!]! @relationship(type: "DIRECTED", direction: IN)
    peopleProduced: [Person!]! @relationship(type: "PRODUCED", direction: IN)
    peopleReviewed: [Person!]! @relationship(type: "REVIEWED", direction: IN, properties: "ReviewedProperties")
    peopleWrote: [Person!]! @relationship(type: "WROTE", direction: IN)
    released: BigInt!
    tagline: String
    title: String!
}

type Person {
    actedInMovies: [Movie!]! @relationship(type: "ACTED_IN", direction: OUT, properties: "ActedInProperties")
    born: BigInt
    directedMovies: [Movie!]! @relationship(type: "DIRECTED", direction: OUT)
    followsPeople: [Person!]! @relationship(type: "FOLLOWS", direction: OUT)
    name: String
    peopleFollows: [Person!]! @relationship(type: "FOLLOWS", direction: IN)
    producedMovies: [Movie!]! @relationship(type: "PRODUCED", direction: OUT)
    reviewedMovies: [Movie!]! @relationship(type: "REVIEWED", direction: OUT, properties: "ReviewedProperties")
    wroteMovies: [Movie!]! @relationship(type: "WROTE", direction: OUT)
}
`;
```

Comment: there similar generation mechanisms available for DBs as well